# Elegant way to add confidence interval text to ggplot, similar to ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I was using the `ggpubr` package and the `ggpubr::stat_cor` function to get some information about the correlation added to a plot. Here is some simple example code:

```
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
x_vec <- runif(n)
y_vec <- 3 + 1.3*x_vec + rnorm(n)
df <- data.frame(x = x_vec, y = y_vec)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_cor(p.accuracy = 0.00001)
```

The resulting plot has a *p*-value in the top left corner:
[image: image with p-value]

I like to have the confidence interval instead, so I made a small PR to `ggpubr` to achieve this, (see [here](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/pull/418)).

I made the change to the package, since that was the fastest way I could figure out to achieve the desired result. I am wondering whether there is a simple elegant way to achieve the same results with `ggplot` directly, or possibly some other package?

**Edit:** I am aware of `geom_text`, and I want to do this, e.g. when I `facet`, such that I use the data defined by the grouping in `ggplot` to achieve this, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(x = x_vec, y = y_vec, grp = sample(1:4, n, replave=TRUE)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group = grp)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(vars(grp)) +
    stat_cor(p.accuracy = 0.00001)
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

Comment: Why not geom_text ? See related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7549694/680068

Comment: Thanks, I want it to work if it is faceted as well. I'll make the question more clear.